# Symfony project not working when run without console

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have been passed down a project that I am supposed to install and configure on a server. I am using nginx w/ php7 and the symfony framework. The problem is, that if I run the server with `php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000` and `nginx` in their folders, the server will not let me access it and I get a 404 error. I can access the info.php if I input the path correctly. If I run the server from the console, with the command `php bin/concole server:run 0.0.0.0:8000 --env=prod`, the server runs fine, with me changing no settings in-between.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html/web;
        index  app.php index.htm index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html/web;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html/web;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  app.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}
```

There was a .htaccess file sent to me with the project, but since this is nginx, and I have no experience in it, I do not know how to convert it. What info do I need to provide to make this work? And how exactly do I make it work? I do not want to always specifically state from the console that I am running in production mode. However, if I do not state, the application always runs in dev mode.

app.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

app_dev.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
|| !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [nginx for symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) and also check your app.php and app_dev.php for any limitation by IP

For Example here is default app_dev.php limitation

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

those code-blocks should be altered or commented out in order to get symfony working on different systemt depending on your setup

Comment: I have edited the question to include the files, if that helps you. If I copy/paste the nginx configuration into my file, should it then work? I do not want to change much of the application, except the php and nginx part, since the rest is supposedly configured properly. I can access the application on a different computer in the same network if I run the server from the bin/console, but not when I run php-cgi and nginx.